# Does the onValue listener for Realtime Database return items in the same order that they are added to the database?

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-realtime-database

I don't see this specified in the docs anywhere. Does this listener return the node's data in the order that it is added to the node? For example, if I add message1, then message2, then message3, does this listener return data in that same order of message1, message2, message3?

The application uses a widget called ChatScreen to show the ReceivedChats widget (chat body) and the MsgInput widget (chat footer). There is no chat header (unless you count the app bar?).

**ChatScreen widget:**

```
class ChatScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  ChatScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final groupIDPath = 'groupChats/0exUS3P2XKFQ007TIMmm';
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        leading: IconButton(
          icon: Icon(Icons.menu),
          color: Colors.white,
          onPressed: () {},
        ),
        title: Text(
          'Group Name',
        ),
        actions: [
          IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.search),
            color: Colors.white,
            onPressed: () {},
          )
        ],
        backgroundColor: Color.fromRGBO(51, 50, 49, 1.0),
        elevation: 0.0,
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Expanded(
            flex: 11,
            child: Row(
              children: [
                Expanded(
                  child: ReceivedChats(groupIDPath: groupIDPath),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      )
    );
  }
}
```

**ReceivedChats widget**

```
class ReceivedChats extends StatefulWidget {
  const ReceivedChats({Key? key, required this.groupIDPath}) : super(key: key);
  final groupIDPath; 

  @override
  _ReceivedChatsState createState() => _ReceivedChatsState();
}

class _ReceivedChatsState extends State<ReceivedChats> {
  late StreamSubscription _receivedChatsStream;
  final _database = FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref();

@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _activateListeners();
  }


  void _activateListeners() {
    _receivedChatsStream = _database.child(groupIDPath).onValue.listen((event) {
      final data = event.snapshot.value;
      print('data: ' + data.toString()); //The data printed here is out of order
    });
  }

@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

//...widget build stuff...//

   }
}
```

**Insert into RTDB:**

```
class MessageDao {

  String groupIDPath; 
  DatabaseReference _messagesRef;
  FirebaseStorage _firebaseStorage;
  String _currentUID;

  MessageDao({required this.groupIDPath}):
        _messagesRef = FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref().child(groupIDPath),
        _firebaseStorage = FirebaseStorage.instance,
        _currentUID = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid.toString();

  //Save a single text message to RTDB
  void saveMessage(ChatData message) async {
    _messagesRef.push().set(message.toJson());
  }
```

**The data currently in RTDB:**

```
{
  "groupChats": {
    "0exUS3P2XKFQ007TIMmm": {
      "-N1HB8ik8RekJGQ-R9X-": {
        "filterID": "",
        "URL": "",
        "text": "1",
        "timestamp": "2022-05-04 22:08:20.782466",
        "type": "1",
        "uid": "f1JqanGGRtd709ia4mxgaM8Apn52"
      },
      "-N1HB9LQ-NAEzp3rNr4V": {
        "filterID": "",
        "URL": "",
        "text": "2",
        "timestamp": "2022-05-04 22:08:23.323476",
        "type": "1",
        "uid": "f1JqanGGRtd709ia4mxgaM8Apn52"
      },
      "-N1HDx2BAMNjio0o6gSU": {
        "filterID": "",
        "URL": "",
        "text": "3",
        "timestamp": "2022-05-04 22:20:35.275138",
        "type": "1",
        "uid": "f1JqanGGRtd709ia4mxgaM8Apn52"
      },
      "-N1HDxeB9V5mvb4i4w9o": {
        "filterID": "",
        "URL": "",
        "text": "4",
        "timestamp": "2022-05-04 22:20:37.772181",
        "type": "1",
        "uid": "f1JqanGGRtd709ia4mxgaM8Apn52"
      },
      "-N1HDy3jGshk_sLK4_oG": {
        "filterID": "",
        "URL": "",
        "text": "5",
        "timestamp": "2022-05-04 22:20:39.471453",
        "type": "1",
        "uid": "f1JqanGGRtd709ia4mxgaM8Apn52"
      },
      "-N1HEYpMpz4L6TMDLlgr": {
        "filterID": "",
        "URL": "",
        "text": "6",
        "timestamp": "2022-05-04 22:23:14.133822",
        "type": "1",
        "uid": "f1JqanGGRtd709ia4mxgaM8Apn52"
      },
      "-N1HE_be1sn86ZNu8KI5": {
        "filterID": "",
        "URL": "",
        "text": "7",
        "timestamp": "2022-05-04 22:23:21.450031",
        "type": "1",
        "uid": "f1JqanGGRtd709ia4mxgaM8Apn52"
      },
      "-N1HEaW0HDvCjqexapy4": {
        "filterID": "",
        "URL": "",
        "text": "8",
        "timestamp": "2022-05-04 22:23:25.121275",
        "type": "1",
        "uid": "f1JqanGGRtd709ia4mxgaM8Apn52"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This depends on some things that we can't see in your question at the moment, including what the code you use to insert the items looks like, and what the data in the database actually looks like. Can you add the first code, and the data at `somePath` (as text, no screenshots please)? You can get this by clicking the "Export JSON" link in the overflow menu (⠇) on your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data).

Comment: Thanks. How are `_database.child(somePath)` and `_messagesRef` initialized? Or even better: can you reproduce the same problem without any variables for which we can't see the value?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen ok I've added simplified code that shows all the unknown stuff. `somePath` = `groupIDPath`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The relevant code in your question is:

```
_database.child('groupChats/0exUS3P2XKFQ007TIMmm').onValue.listen((event) {
  final data = event.snapshot.value;
  print('data: ' + data.toString()); //The data printed here is out of order
})
```

Since you call `event.snapshot.value` on the snapshot of the data at `groupChats/0exUS3P2XKFQ007TIMmm`, you get a `Map` of the data at that path. And the keys in a map are by definition not ordered.

---

If you want to **process** the child nodes in the order that they were return from the database, loop over `event.snapshot.children`:

```
_database.child('groupChats/0exUS3P2XKFQ007TIMmm').onValue.listen((event) {
  event.snapshot.children.forEach((snapshot) {
    print('${snapshot.key}: ${snapshot.value}');
  })
})
```

---

If you want to **return** the child nodes in a specific order from the database, call one of the `orderBy...` method. For example, to order on timestamp:

```
_database.child('groupChats/0exUS3P2XKFQ007TIMmm').orderByChild('timestamp').onValue.listen((event) {
  event.snapshot.children.forEach((snapshot) {
    print('${snapshot.key}: ${snapshot.value}');
  })
})
```

Comment: Wow yup, that was it. Thanks Puff.